# What is wrong with converting size to int?

Tags: c++

Should the following conversion be avoided and for what reason?

```
int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(size(arr)); ++i) // std::size() from C++17
    cout << arr[i];
```

Comment: That code's incomplete (think [mcve]). Also, what do you think (consider "reasonable effort") and why?

Comment: You should always try to avoid casting down as you could lose data.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Oops, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: On most systems a `size_t` is larger than an `int`, so this conversion looses precision (which can lead to problems)

Comment: @UnholySheep Isn't it true that this can only happen for huge arrays that don't fit on the stack anyways?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In this case, it won't break unless someone makes a change. Maybe they wrap your logic in a function and reuse it later with larger arrays. Not a big risk but it's there. But at the same time, what is there to gain from performing the cast? You have zero gains for non-zero risk *and* it takes extra effort to request this conversion.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with this example.  The wrongness comes from using a technique that does not scale/transpose to other containers.  Consistency in styling and coding practices makes maintaining a code base a lot easier and having multiple different types of loop for different situations increases your maintenance cost.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with converting size to int?

There is no problem when the value of interest is small, such as 3.

When the value being cast to `int` is larger than what an `int` can hold, you will an incorrect value after the cast. C++ lets you shoot in the foot if you are determined to do so. You just have to know when you are in danger of doing that and be prepared for the consequences.

Having said that, it is better to stick with code that does not need a cast.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0;  ... )
```

You must have a very compelling reason to use `int` instead of `std::size_t`.

Comment: I'd change the word `precision`. When the value is large, you'll get a flat-out incorrect value (possibly negative), not just an imprecise one.

Comment: @Jeffrey, agreed.

Comment: And I don't think it is specific to C++. C# also lets you do this `var s = (short)(int)5;`

Comment: So, for an array allocated on the stack (which cannot be that large), my conversion is safe, right?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, most likely but you must ask yourself - why use `int` instead of `std::size_t`?

Comment: @RSahu `int` is assumed to be the type with the fastest size for the processor. `size_t` is designed to be the biggest size able to hold any memory offset.

Comment: @Peregring-lk, that would be a compelling reason but only in performace critical parts.

Comment: @RSahu I use `std::size_t` anyway.